# Is webdriver a class or a interface?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

From the [Selenium docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html), WebDriver is an Interface but in Eclipse the package `org.openqa.selenium` is shown as a Class in the Project Explorer. Also, if WebDriver is an Interface, the classes like ChromeDriver or InternetExplorerDriver which implement it should be defining the methods like `.get()` or `.getCurrentUrl()`. Where can we see the method definition of these methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebDriver is a public interface and I do not think ChromeDriver or any other driver implement WebDriver they rather extend *RemoteWebDriver* which is a class.

**Edit**

As I have said the drivers extends RemoteWebDriver and that has the actual implementation of those method..

```
public void get(String url) {
   execute(DriverCommand.GET, ImmutableMap.of("url", url));
}
```

Java source:

```
public interface WebDriver extends SearchContext {
  // Navigation

  /**
   * Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using an HTTP GET operation,
   * and the method will block until the load is complete. This will follow redirects issued either
   * by the server or as a meta-redirect from within the returned HTML. Should a meta-redirect
   * "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait until this timeout is over, since should
   * the underlying page change whilst your test is executing the results of future calls against
   * this interface will be against the freshly loaded page. Synonym for
   * {@link org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Navigation#to(String)}.
   *
   * @param url The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL
   */
```

Comment: But as per the Selenium doc link(http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html) , it is mntioned as : -
Interface WebDriver

    All Superinterfaces:
        SearchContext

    All Known Implementing Classes:
        ChromeDriver, EdgeDriver, EventFiringWebDriver, FirefoxDriver, HtmlUnitDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, MarionetteDriver, OperaDriver, RemoteWebDriver, SafariDriver

Comment: @MainakSikdar I am unable to follow your link.

Comment: @JeffC It does but I do not know where it shows the implementation specifically

Comment: Ah, I think he's talking about http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html

Comment: @Jeff I see where is the confusion now. I will edit my answer to add more info

Comment: @Saifur - Thanks . Got my clarification .

Comment: @JeffC - Thanks to you as well for your help out here .

Answer (score 3):

WebDriver is a public interface, we just define a reference variable(driver) whose type is interface. Now any object we assign to it must be a instance of a class (fireFoxDriver)that implement the interface.